# Conceptual problem with logistic regression using LASSO regularization and cross-validation

Tags: logistic, cross-validation, lasso

When performing k-fold cross-validation (CV) then k training sets are used to generate k models.

This is not a problem to understand when each model contains the same predictors.

The conceptual difficulty I have is that with L1 regularization, which can shrink predictors to zero, it's possible that different predictors are reduced to zero in different iterations through the CV.

For example if there are $3$ predictors $x_1, x_2, x_3$ then the first cycle through the CV loop may generate a model using predictors $x_1, x_2$ but the 2nd cycle may generate a model using predictors $x_1, x_3$ and so on.

Is it OK/justified to then average the estimates of the test error from each fold, when the models may be using entirely different predictors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not only possible that different sets of predictors are used in different folds, it very likely in my experience.

It is however OK to average the error estimates from each fold. You want the instability of the predictor set to go into the error estimate: You are not estimating the expected error of a specific model, you are estimating the expected error of the entire procedure incuding variable selection.

Comment: Also the aim of cross-validation for lasso regression is to validate which model to use, where "model" is parametrized by the number of predictors, not the actual set of chosen predictors.

Comment: Yep, if you use cross validation to select the regularization strength it is the expected result of using a particular $\lambda$ that is interesting, including the variance due to instability of the chosen predictor set.